# Display progress with discrete color fill of an image in silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, animation, controls, progress

In Silverlight, I want to display progress of, for example, an uploading process as a sequence of incremental color fills on an image.

For example,

this is when progress is 0: [image]

this is when 30%:[image]

and 100% is a fully colored image: [image]

How can I control the color fill (I know this will be with the help of a trick, like a final image overlaying the original one or something) to display progress?

My task may be tricky since the image is an OpacityMask for a button in Windows Phone project.

P.S. Just to avoid confusion, as am concerned about the design side of a problem. Logic for hooking up progress with some actions is already in place. I just need to lay out the presentation of a progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

I made an implementation. [A more thorough explanation and download of the code can be found on my blog](http://blogs.infosupport.com/windows-phone-7-custom-progressbar/).

C#:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace CustomControls
{
    [TemplatePart(Name="CLIPRECTANGLE", Type=typeof(RectangleGeometry))]
    public class ImageProgressBar : ProgressBar
    {
        public ImageProgressBar()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ImageProgressBar);
        }

        public ImageSource Source
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public Brush Fill
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(FillProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FillProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FillProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Fill", typeof(Brush), typeof(ImageProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        private RectangleGeometry _clip;

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            _clip = this.GetTemplateChild("CLIPRECTANGLE") as RectangleGeometry;
            this.ValueChanged += ImageProgressBar_ValueChanged;
            this.SizeChanged += ImageProgressBar_SizeChanged;
        }

        void ImageProgressBar_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateClip();
        }

        void ImageProgressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            UpdateClip();
        }

        private void UpdateClip()
        {
            if (_clip != null)
            {
                _clip.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight * ((this.Value - this.Minimum) / (this.Maximum - this.Minimum)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Template: generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControls">
    <Style TargetType="local:ImageProgressBar">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ImageProgressBar">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Source}"
                                   Stretch="Fill" />
                            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Fill}">
                                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Path=Source, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                Stretch="Fill" />
                                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <Rectangle.Clip>
                                    <RectangleGeometry x:Name="CLIPRECTANGLE" />
                                </Rectangle.Clip>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

How to use:

```
<my:ImageProgressBar Width="100"
                        Height="100"
                        Fill="Red"
                        Source="ProgressBar.png"
                        Minimum="100"
                        Maximum="200"
                        Value="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<Slider Margin="0"
        Name="slider1"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Minimum="100"
        Maximum="200"
        Value="125" />
```

Works like a charm:

[image: Example]

**Original Answer**

You could create a Linear gradient brush like this:

```
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="Lime" Offset="1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="Lime" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

And draw the shape/character/text/whatever using this brush.

To show progress just update the Offsets of the middle two gradientstops. You can bind these to make it easier.

To make a real progress bar: Make a Template for the ProgressBar and (multi)bind the Offsets to the Value, Minimum and Maximum of the Progressbar and calculate the offset by `(Value - Minimum)/(Maximum - Minimum)`

To use a bitmap (PNG):

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Image Source="ProgressBar.png"
            Width="100"
            Height="100" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Lime">
        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="ProgressBar.png" />
        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <Rectangle.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,25,100,75"/>
        </Rectangle.Clip>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Replace the Rect when the progress changes. To cut off the correct amount.

Note that the same image is used for the mask.

Comment: Erno, thanks. I think I understood the idea. What you are proposing, is that I need to have a vector representation of my "Region" that want to incrementally fill with color. Then I just apply this gradient brush to it with different offset to display progress. I can't just apply gradient over an PNG image, right?

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov - I made an implementation/CustomControl and added it to my answer.

Comment: Erno, if you could spare a few minutes more, I would really appreciate if you would share a demo project (with source) using your custom control? I've implemented the task myself based on your original answer, but your new solution is defiantly more elegant.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov - I added a link to my blog containing a download of the code at the top of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made a custom ProgressBar the other day. Im not going to tell you exactly how to do yours (because im not a designer), but its not that difficult.

#### Create a Template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomProgressBarTemplate" TargetType="ProgressBar">
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Determinate"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                    <!--Modyify your Storyboard-->
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateGradientFill"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.Transform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].X"
                            Duration="00:00:.5" From="0" To="20" />
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="DeterminateRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <!--Default Root Visuals for either type of ProgressBar-->
        <Border x:Name="ProgressBarTrack" CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
        <Grid x:Name="ProgressBarRootGrid" >
            <Grid Margin="1">
            </Grid>
            <!-- Beginning of Indeterminate Progress Bar Visuals-->
            <Grid x:Name="IndeterminateRoot" Opacity="0.88" Visibility="Collapsed">
            </Grid>
            <!-- Beginning of Determinate Progress Bar Visuals-->
            <Grid x:Name="DeterminateRoot" Margin="1" >   
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In the Determinant and Indeterminant  Grids just draw the image using paths and shapes
*(Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(LinearGradientBrush.Transform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].X" The LinearGradientBrush is the brush I used to fill my objects in the Grids.)*

#### Apply the Template

```
 <ProgressBar Template="{StaticResource CustomProgressBarTemplate}"/>
```

Your going to have to play around with the design make sure your just fill in the correct UIElement. I hope this is a good start for you